# Use Script editor to automatically click a certain area of the application Rekordbox and select a colour

Tags: applescript, rekordbox

I'm using a DJ application called Rekordbox on my Mac running Mojave.

I want to be able to automate the process of clicking on the slots in the top right corner of Rekordbox and select the same set of colours each time for every single track (as displayed in the gif below). How can I achieve this using an Apple Script?

I'm not sure how to click on a specific area of the Application Rekordbox and then automate the process of choosing certain colours for each slot (as shown in the GIF below) using an Script Editor on Mac.

[image]

I'm 1 day old at writing scripts so I just tried some random things off the internet and got a bunch of errors in Apple Script. Any help would be appreciated.